# How to get unique faces in the facepile

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, unique

On a website of mine I'm using the facebook like plugin with show faces enabled. 
The website has more followers than the number of faces that the plugin shows, but the plugin regularly shows duplicate faces.

Is this a known bug or is there something I can do to let the plugin only show unique faces?

Answer (score 1):

This evidently occurs due to a bug/incompatibility in Firefox (up through at least version 16).  It's not present with other browsers such as IE, Chrome, or Safari.